# Conditionally Switching a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

For my app I need the user to input a number, so in order to prevent them from not entering a number I've created an if/else statement that presents the user with an error message if they don't fill out the field, and moves onto the main view of the app if they fill in a number. The only issue is that I'm getting a crash whenever it tries to run the code to bring up the next screen.

```
- (IBAction)budgetButton:(id)sender
{
    myBudget = [self.budgetTextField.text floatValue];
    NSLog(@"myBudget = %.2f", myBudget);
    if (myBudget == 0)
    {
        self.whatsYourBudgetLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"You must enter a budget!")];
    }
    else
    {
        ViewController * nextView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
        self.view.window.rootViewController = nextView;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is borderline incoherent. "I need the user to input a number, so in order to prevent this from happening" You're trying to prevent what you need to happen? Would you please edit to explain your problem more clearly? If your app is crashing, include any error messages.

Comment: try replacing `self.view.window.rootViewController = nextView;` with  `[self presentViewController:nextView animated:NO completion:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

Your code to move to the next view is messed up. 
Have a look at the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method.

You should not change the root of your window. Place a UINavigationController into you window, place your entire view hierarchy in there, and use the default segue mechanisms to navigate.

Comment: Gave that a shot, it still crashes with a SIGABRT.

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"View Controller" sender:self];

Comment: Is the identifier of your segue really "View Controller"?

Comment: I'm new to programming, I've only been doing it for a few months. I don't need these discouraging snarky comments from people when I'm trying to learn stuff.

Comment: That was neither discouraging nor snarky. In your opening post, the name of the identifier was "ViewController". In your comment, it is "View Controller". I was just wondering if you mistyped somewhere. I realize that one is for the segue, and one is for the VC, but it's still worth to make sure you didn't confuse those two somewhere.